# Playstation PIN Bruteforce with CronusMax

Tags: playstation, gpc

I'm trying to create a CronusMac GPC brute-force script that can brute-force **my** Playstation 4 digit password, is this possible with the CronusMax coding language? 
As you may know on PlayStation when entering your PIN code left on the d-pad is for an example 1.

I quickly made this script to test which is covering two different PIN codes and that went good, but of course, you would need some sort of algorithm or something because I couldn't add every combination manually. Is this possible in this coding language?

```
    /* *
* GPC SCRIPT
*
*  GPC is a scripting language with C-like syntax.
*  To learn more access GPC Language Reference on Help menu.
* *********************************************************** */
int turn_on_off;

main {

if(get_val(XB1_LT) && event_press(PS4_SQUARE))//Change for activation combination
turn_on_off=!turn_on_off:

if(turn_on_off){
{combo_run(script_off);
colorled(0,2,0,0);}//red
{combo_run(Bruteforce);
}
if(!turn_on_off)
{combo_run(script_off);
colorled(0,0,0,2);}//purple

}
}
combo Bruteforce {
    set_val(PS4_LEFT, 100);
    wait(50);
    set_val(PS4_LEFT, 0);
    wait(50);
    set_val(PS4_UP, 100);
    wait(50);
    set_val(PS4_UP, 0);
    wait(50);
    set_val(PS4_RIGHT, 100);
    wait(50);
    set_val(PS4_RIGHT, 0);
    wait(50);
    set_val(PS4_LEFT, 100);
    wait(50);
    set_val(PS4_LEFT, 0);
    wait(50);
    set_val(PS4_CIRCLE, 100);
    wait(50);
    set_val(PS4_CIRCLE, 0);
    wait(300);
        set_val(PS4_LEFT, 100);
    wait(50);
    set_val(PS4_LEFT, 0);
    wait(50);
    set_val(PS4_UP, 100);
    wait(50);
    set_val(PS4_UP, 0);
    wait(50);
    set_val(PS4_RIGHT, 100);
    wait(50);
    set_val(PS4_RIGHT, 0);
    wait(50);
    set_val(PS4_TRIANGLE, 100);
    wait(50);
    set_val(PS4_TRIANGLE, 0);
    wait(50);
    set_val(PS4_CIRCLE, 100);
    wait(50);
    set_val(PS4_CIRCLE, 0);
    wait(300);



    }

    combo script_on {

    }

    combo script_off {

    }
    function colorled(c,d,e,f) {
set_led(LED_1,c);
set_led(LED_2,d);
set_led(LED_3,e);
set_led(LED_4,f);
}
```

https://cronusmax.com/manual/math_functions.htm?ms=AgAAACAAAAID&st=MA%3D%3D&sct=MjI2&mw=MzIw